# Проблемы с пониманием цикла foreach

Tags: c++, foreach

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0_0699UZF4&list=PLQOaTSbfxUtCrKs0nicOg2npJQYSPGO9r&index=163&t=329s

Изучение цикла начал в этом видео и сразу же попробовал реализовать его сам и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Автор в видео использовал эту конструкцию:

```
for each (int var in arr) 
  cout << var;
```

У меня же эту конструкцию компилятор не понимает, подчеркивает `each` и `in`

Бродя на просторах интернета наткнулся на другую реализацию этого цикла, она же у меня работает

```
for (auto element : arr)
   cout << arr [element] << " ";
```

Но и с ней не без проблем. Теперь у меня есть несколько вопросов:

1. При использовании рабочей конструкции у меня не выводится `[0]` элемент массива, но, если заменить вывод по индексу выводом напрямую переменной `element`, то такой проблемы не будет
2. В векторе в дополнение, кроме отсутствия `[0]` элемента ещё вылетает программа с ошибкой. Решение то же, как в массиве
3. Почему не понимается конструкция написанная автором?

Answer (score 2):

Начнем с того, что

```
 for each (int var in arr)
```

- это кусок на C# или на C++/CLI. Это другой язык, не стандартный C++.

Далее,

```
for (auto element : arr)
    cout << arr [element] << " ";
```

-это не "другая" реализация, а единственная существующая в актуальных на данный момент стандартах языка (`C++11`,`14`,`17`) конструкция цикла по контейнеру, но применили вы ее неверно - у вас element - это уже элемент из массива, а не индекс элемента в массиве, поэтому писать надо так:

```
for (auto element : arr)
    cout << element << " ";
```

А теперь, чтобы написать совсем хорошо, следует поправить код вот так:

```
for (const auto& element : arr)
{
    cout << element << " ";
}
```

- фигурные скобки следует писать вокруг всех блоков кода, даже если они состоят из одного стейтмента. Это облегчает отладку (всегда можно поставить курсор на нужную строку), облегчает чтение кода (за счет отступов), и главное, позволяет при модификации не переломать логику, добавив строку в блок.
- const заставит компилятор ругаться на вас, если вы заходите изменять элемент в массиве - опечатаетесь, например. Правильный 
  синтаксис для изменения элементов:

  ```
   for (auto& element : arr)
   {
          cin >> element;
   }
  ```

  Классическая ошибка при этом - забыть поставить ссылку

  ```
   for (auto element : arr)
   {
          cin >> element;
   }
  ```

  Если написать вот так, массив изменяться не будет.

Comment: `это кусок на C#` - нет, это ещё и расширение VS для C++. Нестандартное, конечно

Comment: @int3, спасибо. Я конечно помню, что есть такое плод извращений мелкософта над любимым языком, но ну его нафиг :)

Comment: просто не стоит использовать форточку